# Trying to get data from an HTTP request to populate an angular chartjs graph

Tags: angularjs, http, scope, controller, chart.js

Here is my controller:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

angular
.module('ideabank')
.controller('ProfileController', ProfileController);

ProfileController.$inject = ['$http', '$scope'];

function ProfileController($http, $scope) {

$scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "Novemeber", "December"];

$scope.getProfile = getProfile;

function getProfile() {
  $http
    .get("http://localhost:3000/profile")
    .then(function (response) {
      var profileData = populateChart(response.data.pastIdeas);
      $scope.data = [];
      $scope.data.push(profileData);
      console.log($scope.data);
    });
}

function populateChart(pastIdeas) {
  console.log(pastIdeas);
  var amounts = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  for(var i=0; i < pastIdeas.length; i++) {
    var ideaDate = new Date(pastIdeas[i].date);
    var month = ideaDate.getMonth();
    console.log(month);
    if(month === 0){
      amounts[0] = 1 + amounts[0];
      console.log(amounts);
    }
  amounts[5] = 10;
  return amounts;
  }
}
}
})();
```

Here is the HTML for the chart:

```
<div ng-controller="ProfileController">
  <canvas id="radar" class="chart chart-radar"
      chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML for the button, where users go to their profile:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Idea Bank</a>
  <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down" ng-     controller="ProfileController">
    <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
    <li ng-if="vm.loggedIn"><a ui-sref='profile' ng-click="getProfile()">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a ng-if="!vm.loggedIn" ng-click="vm.showModal()">Create or Login</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a quick breakdown. When a user clicks the profile button it should take them to their profile and make an HTTP call and populate that specific user data to the chart.

However, for some reason I cant get the data from the HTTP call to populate the graph correctly.

If I, just manually type graph data beneath the $scope.labels.

eg. $scope.data = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6] ];

Then the graph shows with that data. But i cannot make it show with the data from the http call and the populate chart function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't have `ng-controller="ProfileController"` inside the chart.html again..which will create a new instance of your controller again.

Comment: Put a break point after the http call after the promise: `.then(function (response) {
      var profileData = populateChart(response.data.pastIdeas);` What is the value of `response`?

Comment: do some basic debugging to see what actually gets returned from `populateChart()`. We can't do that for you